# Manually merging Core Data objects

Tags: ios, core-data, restkit

In an app using RestKit, I sometimes create two instances of the 'same' object: the app may be doing multiple mapping operations simultaneously and create a full object in one and a placeholder one with only its server-assigned unique ID in another. These objects are separate Core Data objects and have different `objectID`s, despite having the same `serverID`s.

Because I don't want to show the same object twice, I want merge these 'duplicate' objects. Currently I'm checking in `validateForInsert:` whether the object is a 'duplicate' of an existing one and am returning an error if so.

I then take all errors, merge the conflicting objects (keeping whichever is oldest), and delete the duplicates.

This is where things go wrong, and I have crashes: some parts of my app - UI or otherwise - have references to the 'deleted' 'duplicate' NSObject, which is now a fault. It gets referenced and the fault cannot be fulfilled, as the `NSManagedObject` no longer exists.

How do I avoid this?

I'd really like to avoid auditing every reference to a managed object context and have to always check whether it has become a fault and should be replaced with the other, correct `NSManagedObject` that I'd have to lookup.

Answer (score 0):

The first recommendation would be to not run the requests concurrently. Anything other than this option requires leg work from you to do the merge (as you currently are) and manage the references.

If you need to merge then your current approach is ok. Updating the references is obviously more of an issue. You can do better than deleting the youngest one, but that's kind of beside the point.

The simplest way to manage the references is to be using `NSFetchedResultsController`s, because they will see the additions and removals and update for you.

If you explicitly pass references to managed objects around then you need to monitor for deletions. The most likely route is to post notifications of deletions (or use the built in change notifications) and drop your references (probably executing a fetch request for the replacements).